# X11 tunnelling through SSH from Fedora 3 server to Windows Vista client fails to work

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, cygwin, x11forwarding

Okay, I've tried using Xming and PuTTY, as well as Cygwin/X and Cygwin ssh, and it is not working.

I've been able to run X applications locally, so it's not a client-side X problem.

I've connected to the server using

```
ssh -X user@server
```

and ended up with this:

```
local-user@client: ~$ ssh -X user@server
user@server's password:
Last login: Sun Jul 19 15:26:46 2009 from 192.168.100.147
 [user@server ~]$  xclock &
[1] 27770
[user@server ~]$ Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0    

[1]+  Exit 1                  xclock
[user@server ~]$
[user@server ~]$
```

Here's the relevant snippet of my sshd_config

```
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

I can't seem to find ssh_config on the client-side.  /etc/ssh doesn't exist.

Comment: Do X programs work from the Cygwin prompt before running the ssh client?

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu - Yes

Comment: I am using Xmanager for such tasks- it is a software for windows, which allows X-over ssh. It may help you, try it.

Comment: Fedora 3 is unsupported for over 5 years, you really should upgrade. CentOS should provide adequate compatibility with old software.

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify your PuTTY settings; Once you have entered your server name or ip-address, change the SSH -> X11 settings: Check the "Enable X11 forwarding" box, and type localhost:0 into the "X display location". Don't forget to go back to "Session" and save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun ssh but with the -v flag as well.  It is possible that sshd on the remote side can't find xauth to set your mit magic cookie for X authentication.

Comment: xauth is in the $PATH for the daemon account, that can't be that.  I'll try to post ssh -v if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the question to be "X11 tunnelling through SSH **to** Fedora 3 server **from** Windows Vista client fails to work". (Interchanged to and from)

In that case have a look at my answer and even other people answers at [Remote-desktop into Ubuntu 9.04 from a Windows PC](https://serverfault.com/questions/35651/remote-desktop-into-ubuntu-9-04-from-a-windows-pc/35665#35665).

Comment: No, that response is inadequate.  I want to tunnel through SSH, not use a unencrypted X11 connection.  Keep in mind that I can't open any ports on the client!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Windows X servers. But the following two points are generic to any X server.

1. I have encountered a situation when the X server is configured to not listen TCP
   connections. In this case ssh is not able to forward the X connection. Could you check
   that port 6000 is open in the machine where you run the X server. (In Linux this could 
   be done with

   sudo netstat -antp | grep 6000

   I do not know if it works in Cygwin as well?)
2. Maybe the X server is refusing connections unless you tell it is safe. (In Linux/Unix
   X11 server this can be done with

   xhost +hostname

   where 'hostname' is the host name you want to allow access to your X server.)
3. The previous mention of using -v (maybe multiple times) for ssh is worth diamonds to
   find what is going wrong.

Comment: No, the WINDOWS X SERVER WORKS FINE.  The SERVER'S X SERVER WORKS FINE.  It's the SSH TUNNELING THAT FAILS!

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 11 fix

sudo vim /etc/gdm/custom.conf

Your file should have following lines (there may be other lines so leave them be)

[xdmcp]

[security]
DisallowTCP=false

then restart X. 
It works...you might need to tweek your firewall though

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `-Y` rather than `-X`. Basically this sets up the trust properly (details from the ssh man page below).

> -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
>
> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the user’s X authorization database) can access the local X11 display through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
>
> For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for more information.
>
> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using Xvnc. On Fedora you can choose to start several X Desktops that you can easily connect to and detach from at any time. One downside might be that you have an X desktop running *all the time*. If absolute performance is an issue, then think again (but hey, if it's idle for some time, the kernel will swap that out to disk anyway). A nice benefit however, is that you can start a task (in a gnome app, or in a terminal) and disconnect while it's still running. You can connect at anytime with any vnc viewer (using portforwarding for added security) to monitor it's progress.

Comment: I have VNC working, I can connect over a non-secure connection to it.  What I want to do is use SSH to secure the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Or ... just use [NoMachine's](http://www.nomachine.com/) software which always uses compressed X over SSH. Only an RPM install away.

Answer (score 0):

If your local X server works fine and listens on local network socket (should be doing it on port 6000, check it!) you can manually forward the connection.

*I'm assuming here that there's no X server running on the server.*

Forward localhost port 6000 from the server (so that SSH would listen on port 6000 on the server) to local port 6000. After connecting do:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xclock
```

you should get the `xclock` from the server shown on your local X server.